# The requested store is not found. when I deleted the extra store from Magento 2.1 store view.

Tags: magento-2.1, store-view, stores

The requested store is not found only on category tab in admin else everything is working fine if I deleted the extra store from Magento 2.1 store view.

**How i set the one store view for all. product upload and layout.**

Because while uploading products nos of Product URL created for all store ids 1,2,3,4,5 in the database. As I required only one store view that store id is 2.

Everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

Check-in error log file which store is pointing actually. there you got the store id so revert back or enable the store which you have deleted. And add put that store's website id in website column when you going to upload product via csv. that will solve the multiple url problems for all stores.